# Checking if there is enough stock in the inventory

Tags: c#, mysql, datagridview

Anyone who can help me here? I've been dealing with this for months but I can't seem to find the solution.

As the title says, I need to check if there are enough ingredients for every meal when I click that certain meal in my POS.

I have these table structures in my database..

[image]

[image]
[image]

As you can see, every serving of Fried Chicken consists of the following ingredients coming from my inventory.
Lets say there aren't enough stock for a certain ingredient, a message box will appear saying there are no stocks left in the inventory else it will be added in the datagridview. This will occur once I click the Fried Chicken in my POS.

Here is my code for that:

```
        cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM tblmenu", dbConn);
        MySqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        while (rdr.Read())
        {
            Button btn = new Button();
            btn.Name = rdr["menuID"].ToString();
            btn.BackgroundImage = Image.FromStream(ms);
            btn.BackgroundImageLayout = ImageLayout.Stretch;

            btn.Width = 120;
            btn.Height = 100;

            btn.Click += delegate
            {

                MySqlConnection cnn2 = new MySqlConnection(sqlConn.connString);
                cnn2.Open();
                cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT menuID, menuName, menuPrice, menuCategory FROM tblmenu WHERE menuID = @id", cnn2);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", btn.Name);
                MySqlDataReader rdr2 = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                if (rdr2.Read() == true)
                {

                    dataGridView1.Rows.Add(rdr2.GetInt32("menuID"), rdr2.GetString("menuName").ToUpper(), 1, rdr2.GetDouble("menuPrice"), rdr2.GetDouble("menuPrice"));

                }
            };
```

Then the function for adjusting the quantity in the datagridview

```
void quantity_change(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var row = dataGridView1.CurrentRow;

        if (row == null || row.Index < 0)
            return;
        var unit = (sender == btnAdd) ? 1 : -1;

        var quantity = Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells["Quantity"].Value) + unit;


        row.Cells["Quantity"].Value = quantity;
        var rate = Convert.ToDouble(row.Cells["Price"].Value);
        row.Cells["TotalAmount"].Value = quantity * rate;

    }
```

I really hope that someone can help me here since this is the only thing that I need to do to finish my project.

Comment: What is the current output you are getting from your code?

Comment: I can add the menu/item in the datagrid, but I don't really know which or what to use to check if there are still enough stock for the ingredients in the inventory.

Comment: What table engine do you use? Innodb?

Answer (score 0):

In the `btn.Click += delegate` you shoudn't query on the `tblmenu` but select from the `Ingredients` table and use a where on the `MenuID`. Also Join the Inventory to it, to select the current stock value.

Something like:  *(not tested, but might give a hint)*

```
SELECT menuID, menuName, menuPrice, menuCategory, tblinventory.Quantity AS StockQuantity, tblingredients.Quantity AS IngredientQuantity
FROM tblingredients
INNER JOIN tblinventory on tblingredients.InvID == tblinventory.ID
WHERE menuID = @id
```

And compare on the results the `StockQuantity` AND `IngredientQuantity`

---

There are some problems with the code:

`dataGridView1.Rows.Add(rdr2.GetInt32("menuID"), rdr2.GetString("menuName").ToUpper(), 1, rdr2.GetDouble("menuPrice"), rdr2.GetDouble("menuPrice"));`

why add *menuPrice* twice?

---

The `MenuName` in ingredients menu is redundant. You should remove it. Because the ingredients is an intersection between the inventory and the menu. You don't want to store the menu name each ingredient

---

You shouldn't be using `btn.Name` here => `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", btn.Name);` use the `btn.Tag` instead.

---

How are `units` related. There could be a difference between the unit of `ingredients` and the unit of the `inventory`.

Comment: Thank you for answering but how should I compare the two? (Stock Quantity and the Ingredient Quantity). I've already come up with that idea that you've given. I'm adding the menuPrice twice since there are two columns in my dgv which is the selling price and the price for adjusting the quantity.

Comment: a, my bad. you just want to add the menu to the grid, not the ingredients. Before you add the menu, you should check the stock. (with the query I gave you) Then with a while loop you should check each ingredient for the stock.

Comment: 1. The availability should be checked twice: when the list is generated and when a meal is selected. 2. During the 2nd check the records should be locked if use select for checking, just in case the same ingredients re used at another POS.

Comment: Still need some help. I am comparing the stock quantity and ingredients quantity, but when I do, the records that has been saved in my database (ex. 2 burger) in the ingredients table, will show 3 messagebox else if there's enough stock, 3 rows will appear in the datagridview.

Comment: Use a boolean and set it when the stock is too low. Create a new selection to add the menu instead of the ingredients